# vim displaying a 'page break' at line ending, with at's in margin (@)

Tags: encoding, vi, line-breaks, vim

I have an ANSI XML file using windows linebreaks.

At the end of a line, I have CRLF[space][space] (0 x 0D 0A 20 20)

In other text editors, this displays as newline, space space. in VIM, it appears to be doing a sort of 'page break' instead of a linebreak, with a screenfull of @ characters down the left margin.

I have tried reloading the file using different encodings and explicit linebreak formats, but it made no useful difference.

Does anyone understand this phenomenon?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot?!

Comment: Those `@`s usually appear when a wrapped line is too long to be displayed in a single block.

Comment: try execute one command:`set display=lastline` see if it changes

Comment: @romainl as a matter of fact, the next line is very long. I don't quite understand your comment, however. Could you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: `:help 'display'` answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just trying to show a long line all at once. You can turn it off with lastline

'display' 'dy'      string  (default "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Change the way text is displayed.  This is comma separated list of
    flags:

```
lastline    When included, as much as possible of the last line
        in a window will be displayed.  When not included, a
        last line that doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.

uhex        Show unprintable characters hexadecimal as <xx>
        instead of using ^C and ~C.
```